# Go mocking - Mock struct

Tags: unit-testing, go

I need to mock 3-rd party struct defined in as:

```
type SafeFormatAndMount struct {
    Interface
    Exec
}
```

Struct and also Interface and Exec are defined in the same file.
I succeed to mock each Interface separately by running:

> mockgen -destination=/root/mock/mock_mount_Interface_Exec.go -package=mocks k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/util/mount Interface,Exec

But it creates two mocks while I need to create a single mock which will mock SafeFormatAndMount 
How can I do it?
Thank you

Comment: You can't mock a struct. What you should do is use the original struct and set its `Interface` and `Exec` embedded fields using the generated mocks for those two interfaces.

Comment: In addition to these 2 interfaces SafeFormatAndMount contains a method I also need to mock. So the suggested solution isn't enough. Is there any way to mock the interfaces and additional method?

Comment: You can't mock that func since it is declared on a concrete struct. One thing you can do is to declare a new custom interface which will declare all the methods you need to use from `SafeFormatAndMount` including the methods from the two embedded interfaces. Then refactor your code that depends on the concrete struct to instead depend on the new interface, then generate a mock for the new interface and use that in the tests and use `SafeFormatAndMount` when you run in normal, non-test, mode.

Comment: Yes, what mkopriva said. To be able to mocking functions, you'll need to step back to interfaces. Those are the real plug-n-play options in golang.